# Why is my flask + sqlite program throwing 404?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, http-status-code-404

I am trying to insert values from an HTML form into my sqlite3 database. However, I am facing a 404 issue when I click the submit button on the form. It does not save anything in the database and does not render the second HTML page.

The following link contains the code for the app.py server code:
https://pastebin.com/h4616M0G

Following is the error message I received:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2022 16:10:40] "GET /home2.html?name=John&email=sdbjhc%40gmail.com&phone=93429348&password=sjhdbvjs HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Please post your code in the post

Answer (score 1):

There is no route for `/home2.html` in your Python code. You defined `/registerCustomer`, so you must change your form action to this one or change your route.

Answer (score 0):

The log shows a GET request to the website. This means that the browser sends a GET request instead of a POST request.

The http-parameters containing the form values hint in the direction that in the html source of the website the form element is missing the `method="POST"` attribute.

The 404-error appeares when a flask route doesn't exist. The route `/home2.hmtl` doesn't exist as the route in the app is `/registerCustomer`.

To fix this issue add the `method="POST"` attribute and the correct url:

```
<form action="/registerCustomer" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```